# What is the difference between concepts and things?

Tags: ontology, hegel

I read that in Hegel’s ontology, concepts and things are the same thing. The universe itself is constructed from concepts, so in a way, reality is made of ideas.

Is there a deep difference other than the minor “a thing is a specific instantiation of some concept in ‘the real world’”?

Comment: Please give a precise reference to the relevant passage from Hegel's work, thanks.

Comment: This is the idealistic pow...for realism, things and concepts are different: concepts are what are predicated of things and not vice-versa.

Comment: You can kick things. Concepts don't exist, they are human delusions. See: *Heart Sutra*. Repeat until enlightened.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA There was no serious idealist who confused predicates with what is predicated. It's not "the idealist pov". If anything, what you described is nominalism.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gross misinterpretation of Hegel.

Like I tried to explain [in this answer of mine](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/79288/17209), Hegel's epistemology is very peculiar and I think if one is to "simplify" it in a paraphrase using his own terminology, it would be something like:

> The concept, the mere abstraction of an object (not unlike Plato's ideas), does bear no reality *in itself* just as a mere particular, the subjective representation of an object, will have reality *for itself*. To be real, they need to come together in a way where the particular (what we would describe as empirical reality of an object these days) is in accordance with the concept of it, *coming to itself as an object in and of itself* through acquiring (or our thought and practice enabling us to percieve and understand it having) the properties it *should "ideally" have*. Only then, the object exists as its idea in in its reality.

I cannot fathom how helpful this is to anyone who never studied Hegel though.

In his later philosophy of the *Encyclopedia of Philosophical Science* (§§160+),¹ he equates Geist with Concept as the absolute, concrete, determinate existence that differentiates itself in itself through judgements (through which it ultimately falls into concepts and particulars in the above terminology). In a sense, that means that Concept is *everything* - but at once. Again, this does not seem to fit hat you write.

¹ Cheers to abracadabra for pointing me there with their answer.

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't think this. Hegel rarely ever speaks of *concepts* like *dog*, *house*, *liver*, *window*, *chair* etc. You probably mean **the Concept** which is Hegel's name for what Kant calls *the synthetic unity of apperception*. Hegel says that all *concepts* (like *dog*, *chair* etc.) acquire their determinacy only in relation to **the Concept**.

Comment: Could you name a source for this terminology? I find it hard to reconcile it with his works I read in German or the English secondary literature I read so far.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Encyclopaedia Logic §164

Comment: Ah, I see. You mean where he says that Geist is absolute concreteness and thus the concept of concepts containing all individual concepts, if you like.

Comment: I don't think that one should equate Geist with Kant's synthetic unity of apperception, though. Also, this reminds me that I should read the Encyclopedia one day. I only read the *Phenomenology* and *Philosophy of Right*.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking No, I don't want to identify Kant's unity of apperception with Geist, but with Concept. I mean this quote: "...what are also called concepts, and indeed determinate concepts, for instance man, house, animal, etc.".

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Although the quote about the Geist is too significant, just not exactly what I meant.

Comment: You should read a bit higher where he writes exactly that the Concept (I don't like the capitalisation in the English translation tbh) is Geist. German: "Das Absolut-Konkrete ist der Geist (s. Anm. § 159), - der Begriff, insofern er als Begriff, sich unterscheidend von seiner Objektivität, die aber des Unterscheidens unerachtet die seinige bleibt, existiert." - English "The absolute-concrete is the Geist (see annotation § 159) - the concept insofar it is, as Concept, differentiating itself from its objectivity, which despite the differentiation remains its own, does exist." - Geist = Concept